# Unable to replace \\n with empty string using java

Tags: java

```
Trying to replace \\n from a String with "",
after removing the \\n the expected o/p  would be:  "This is not working ";
Tried samples : 

 String str = "This \\nis \\n\\nnot \\n\\nworking ";

   str.replaceAll("\\n","");
```

- This is not working .
  Could you please Help me out how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `\\\\n` instead of a `\\n`. This should work:

```
String str = "This \\nis \\n\\nnot \\n\\nworking ";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\n",""));
```

Comment: Working at my end. What is the issue you are facing when you run it?

Comment: its returning me like this, This \nis \n\nnot \n\nworking
String str = "This \\nis \\n\\nnot \\n\\nworking ";

Comment: Maybe an environment related issue. Try it on an online Java compiler, something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php. If possible, update your question with a screenshot of code and output.

Comment: I don't know how did it work for you , its in same state in the above online compiler as well
public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "This is \\n\\nnot \\n\\nworking";
        String str  = s.replaceAll("\\n","");
        System.out.println(str);
     }
o/p : This is \n\nnot \n\nworking

Comment: I think you updated your question, now it has `\\n` as part of the string, so in this case you'll definitely need `\\\\n`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [online regex generator](https://regex101.com/) to explore more patterns. This would really help!

**Meanwhile I guess below example should serve your use case :**

```
public class RegularExpression {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String originalString = "This \\nis \\n\\nnot \\n\\nworking ";

    String newString = originalString.replaceAll("\\\\n","");

    System.out.println(newString);

}
```

}